# Does image preloading really work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, image-preloader

I added images through `<img>` tag in one HTML page and then preloaded the same through another HTML file. This was the YSlow graph for the HTML page without preloading.

[image]

and when I preloaded the same 8 images, this was what the YSlow graphs showed me:
[image]

I know that there will always be an additional HTTP request for the jQuery file when I include the preloading hoopla.

So does this mean that the load time will always be greater if I preload the images? If that's the case what's all the hype of preloading about?

--Edit--

I also cleared cache before testing both the HTML pages. I took these screenshots only after clearing cache for each instance.

Comment: [use image preload script.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628332/preload-image-with-javascript-and-display-when-ready/22628418#22628418)

Answer (score 1):

You preload images that are not yet shown to the user but when the user wants to see them won't wait for loading. Like when you have an hover on an image and it changes.

But if image is big and user hovers the first time than he will wait for loading. If you preload the second image than won't wait.

Preloading is ideal in some cases but not all.