# How to call preloaded images

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery preload plugin from here http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/preload-images-with-jquery-preload-plugin/

So I'm preloading in the beginng the images, I can see in chrome -> network that is downloading the images.
But they are not appended to any html tag.

```
$.preload( 
'/dada/spot-the-differences/images/levels/2.png',
'/dada/spot-the-differences/images/levels/22.png',
'/dada/spot-the-differences/images/levels/3.png',
'/dada/spot-the-differences/images/levels/32.png',
'/dada/spot-the-differences/images/levels/4.png',
'/dada/spot-the-differences/images/levels/42.png',
'/dada/spot-the-differences/images/levels/5.png',
'/dada/spot-the-differences/images/levels/52.png'
);
```

I'm using this images in a game with levels.

When the level changes if i call this jquery: (response.next will be equal to: 1,2,3,4,5 as levels are changing.)

```
$('.imgdiff-1').attr('src', 'images/levels/'+response.next+'.png');
$('.imgdiff-2').attr('src', 'images/levels/'+response.next+'2.png');
```

It downloads the images again, instead of using the ones that it downloaded in the begning in the DOM.

Any thoughts?

Comment: [have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628332/preload-image-with-javascript-and-display-when-ready/22628418#22628418)

Comment: I want to use <img> not background-image

Comment: That script loads the image whatever you could do it with img or background.

Comment: Check that you dont have checked the disable cache feature

Comment: It's not disabled, after you run the game first time it will be cached for future tryes. But I just want to make the user experience nice from the first try.

Comment: image paths that you preload and that you assign to src attribute later look different

Comment: Because when I preload them I have to put the src from the root of the server and later I put the root from the folder where the application is. But both are referencing to the same images.

Comment: what if you try to preload it without any external plugin, e.g. with jquery `$('<img/>')[0].src='image\path'`, or in plain javascript like `var img=new Image();img.src='image\path'`

Comment: for the jquery version how do i call after the image.src?