# Display low resolution image and then high resolution image after few seconds (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to display lots of images on a HTML webpage, but want to display a low resolution image at first and then display a high resolution image after few seconds.

Reason is because client internet connection speed can't be determined, so i need to optimize the way my website loads its images.

I have actually gone through this link on Stackoverflow [Fast Image loading methods, low to high res with multiple backgrounds - javascript solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906266/fast-image-loading-methods-low-to-high-res-with-multiple-backgrounds-javascri)

Tried to run the sample javascript code found in the answer but didnt seem to work.

And then i read about [Progressive JPEG's](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-11.html), but don't know how to go about it also.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you generate/create your images as to whether they will be progressive or not. If your images are not progressive, and you have ImageMagick installed (many Linuuxes do) you can convert an image from non-progressive (also known as `baseline JPEG`) to progressive with this command and try it out on your website:

```
convert nonProgressive.jpg PJPEG:Progressive.jpg
```

ImageMagick is available for Windows, OSX, Linux for free from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Another way to minimise image sizes is with `jhead`, and the following command strips out all EXIF information from your image to make it smaller - information removed is things like GPS coordinates, date and time picture was taken, camera model and focal length and shutter speed.

```
jhead -purejpg image.jpg
```

**Updated Answer**

In response to your further question about doing ALL your images, I am not here to tell you what to do! It is your website - you can do as you wish. I was merely suggesting a way for you to try it out on an image and see if you like the results and the performance. If you want to apply to it all your images, it is quite easy, either using standard tools, or GNU Parallel which will do the job in a fraction of the time by using all your CPU cores. Whatever you do, I would `urge you to make a backup first` in case anything goes wrong or you later decide progressive, EXIF-stripped JPEGs are not for you.

So, after making a backup, you could do one of these options assuming your website is in /var/www:

```
find /var/www -iname "*.JPG" -exec convert "{}" "PJPEG:{}" \;
```

or the same again, with EXIF-stripping, and also colour profile, stripping:

```
find /var/www -iname "*.jpg" -exec convert "{}" -strip "PJPEG:{}" \;
```

Or you could use GNU Parallel, like this to use all your CPU cores:

```
find /var/www -iname "*.jpg" | parallel convert "{}" -strip "PJPEG:{}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark Setchell   for your answer, Am i to run this code for every image on my website on my Linux terminal? . Because i have up to like 15,000 images on my website.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, Sorry i had been offline since then. I tried it and it worked. I will pick it as my answer ....Although i have a question, If you take a look at the way sites like facebook display pictures, it seems they have 2 version of every picture, They first display a very low quality (Fully) not progressively, then after some seconds display the full quality. I hope am not getting confused here.