# Image loading like google image PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, image

I came across the problem of image loading in website.

It's need to load 3 high resolution images in home page, and when open, it's showing website other contents first and load this images which is fine for now.

But it's slightly awkward, and would like to have similar image loading process like Google image search.

When I click image in Google, it shows blurred or pixelate image which seems like low resolution and lower size and loading original image a bit later.

They might use special thing as they are Google, but if someone have done this kinds of things before, I need your help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want what are called "[progressive JPEGs](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/progressive-jpegs-a-new-best-practice/)", where multiple images of varying quality are saved in one file, and the browser loads the low resolution images quickly to get something in the page, and replaces it with higher resolution images once they've been loaded.

[Here's a tutorial](http://peteschuster.com/2013/01/saving-jpegs-for-the-web-setting-photoshop-up-for-progressive-jpegs/) on saving JPEGs for the web as progressive in Photoshop

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery. The following is a general idea, not an exact code.

For each image use something like:

```
<div>
    <img id="myimg" src="" style="display:none">
    <img src="low-res-version link">
</div>
```

You should also keep a low res image.

Use jQuery to set your images src after the page loades, and use the [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function to [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) the low res image.

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('#myimg').attr('src', 'link to the image').on('load', function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'block').next().remove();
}
```

You can also check this question: [Fast Image loading methods, low to high res with multiple backgrounds - javascript solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906266/fast-image-loading-methods-low-to-high-res-with-multiple-backgrounds-javascri)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I choose resolutions from the server-side;
loading the low-res immediately in a z-index=0 object,
loading the one or more hi-res objects into negative z-index objects
and then at onload(), choose which object should be on top